# split content with jquery and <hr> tag and put it to another div

Tags: jquery, split

I got with some text entered with tinyMCE in a div class'.category-info'. Text can be splited with **hr** tag. What I want to do is split the text with jQuery and wrap the second part of the text (after **hr** tag) into separate div. My code looks like this:

```
var str = $('.category-info').html();
var splitter = $(str.split('<hr>')[1]).html();
$(splitter).wrap('<div class="news-part" />');
```

When I alert variable splitter it shows html content (but what's weired without p tag which is right after hr tag) but it's not wrapped into div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To wrap all part after hr, I would do something like below,

```
var str = $('.category-info').html();
str = str.split('<hr>');

$('.category-info').html(str[0] + 
          '<div class="news-part">' + 
             str[1] + 
          '</div>');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/p4JFx/2/)

If I understood correctly, you want to wrap the element after `hr` with `<div class="news-part" />`.. Then try below code,

```
$('.category-info hr').next().wrap('<div class="news-part" />');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/p4JFx/1/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply - the problem is that I want to wrap not one element but all the part of the text after hr tag. This text can contain multiple <p> <span> etc. tags. So that's the problem

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you want...

```
var str = $('.category-info').html();
var splitter = str.split('<hr>')[1];
$(splitter).wrap('<div class="news-part" />');
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which I found a solution to after reading this post. This will split content at an element and wrap everything after the element (up to the next one) with a div:

```
$('.category-info hr').each(function(){ 
    $(this).nextUntil('hr').wrapAll('<div class="news-part"/>');
});
```

This will only work in your case when you have an `<hr>` element **before** each item (including one at the start).

Answer (score 0):

When you use $.wrap(), you should attach it to a selector of the element that you'd like to wrap.

The way I understand your problem, try this:

```
$('.category-info hr:nth-child(2)').wrap('<div class="news-part" />');
```